# Parse nested matches using regex

Tags: regex, recursion, lexer

I would like to use [regex](http://regexpal.com/) to look inside a string for the smallest sequence that fits a starting and ending delimiter (taking an escape character into account). For example, if I had the following string I would want to locate the lowest matches `[ two ]` and `[ four \[ five \] ]` while ignoring the match they are contained in `[ one ... three ... six]`.

```
zero [ one [ two ] three [ four \[ five \] ] six ] seven
```

So far I have the following regex which uses negative look-behinds to check and isn't quite caching the last `]` in the second match.

```
(\[)(?:(?!(?:[^\\])\1|\]).)*]
```

My goal is to have a simple parser I can use to process simple nested command blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
\[(?:\\[\[\]]|[^\[\]])*]
```

See it working: http://www.rubular.com/r/cAajtm2wxw

Explanation:

```
\[                # opening bracket
(?:               # start of non-capturing group (repeat zero or more times)
   \\[\[\]]         # backslash followed by [ or ]
   |                # OR
   [^\[\]]          # any character except [ or ]
)*                # end of non-capturing group
]                 # closing bracket
```

Note that this isn't quite safe because in a string like `[ one \\[ two ] three ]` the backslash is escaped, so the backslash before the `[` should not escape it.

To fix this you could use the following:

```
\[(?:(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\[\[\]]|[^\[\]])*]
```

This changes the single escaped backslash `\\` in the original regex to the following regex which checks for an odd number of backslashes:

```
(?<!\\)           # fail if previous character is a backslash
(?:\\\\)*         # some even number of backslashes
\\                # one more backslash to make it odd
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/BhQzLQpyB9

Comment: Thank you! You helped me foresee problems I didn't even think of. Also, the addition of creative logic (using 2 even + 1 odd before 1 odd) is pretty neat.